# setText is slow with sprite-kit

Tags: sprite-kit, settext

Our first game is about to go live. We have found that the performance of sprite kit is reasonably good. We are moving hundreds of sprites around and have effect nodes and sounds. However you must not dare to set the score. The SKLabelNode is very slow.

after running diagnostics it was found that the following code was the culprit.

```
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",my_score];
```

In the diagnostic tool the setText command was showing as the most expensive. We even made sure that it was not being called that often. It still resulted in a lag causing the sprites to jerk/jitter/hickup. Once we removed the line...we got smooth motion.

If we are not able to use the SKLabelNodes inside the game scene, what other options are there?

Comment: bitmap fonts, for this very reason. try glyph designer, comes with sk bitmap font node

Comment: @LearnCocos2D FYI see my answer below - it *can* be 'quicker' to load a font, if the font name is specific, e.g. ChalkboardSE-Regular.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful you aren't loading the *entire* font family.
If I load "Chalkboard SE" it will take 4-6 seconds, and appear to work.

But if I load ChalkboardSE-Regular , it's virtually instantaneous ~100ms or less.

Once it's added to the scene, subsequent calls are very quick. But if you transition to another scene, it might re-load, so do it early.

I did some testing with font families first, and the results are pretty catastrophic. Caching strong references doesn't help. https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2015/01/14/ios-spritekit-font-loading-times-of-sklabelnodes/